# How to use an async database call to set a variable with useState() and useEffect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-hooks

I'm trying to set a variable with a simple GET database call. The database call is returning the data correctly, but the variable remains undefined after every re-render. Code is below... the `getMyThing()` function in the `useState()` function is working correctly and returning the data I want.

```
import { getMyThing } from '../../utils/databaseCalls'

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [myThing, setMyThing] = useState(getMyThing(id));

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyThing(myThing)
  }, [myThing]);
}
```

My thinking here was to use `useState()` to set the initial state of the `myThing` variable with the data returned from my database. I assume it's not immediately working since a database call is asynchronous, so I thought I could use `useEffect()` to update the `myThing` variable after the response of the database call completes, since that would trigger the `useEffect()` function because I have the `myThing` variable included as a dependency.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers everyone, but I still can't get it to work by calling the `getMyThing` function asynchronously inside `useEffect()`. Is something wrong with my database call function? I guess it's not set up to a return a promise? Here's what that looks like:

```
export const getMyThing = (id) => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/thing/' + id)
        .then(response => {
            return(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Comment: Your `getMyThing` function doesn't return anything so it's just fire and forget. You should return the promise from your function. Add a `return` statement before `axios.get('http://localhost:4000/thing/' + id)`. In its current state, it would always return `undefined`.

Comment: Awesome yeah, that was the problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **should** do all your side effects(fetching data, subscriptions and such) in `useEffect` hooks and event handlers. Don't execute async logic in `useState` as you just assign the promise itself to the variable and not the result of it. In any case, it is a bad practice and it won't work. You should either:

```
import { getMyThing } from '../../utils/databaseCalls'

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [myThing, setMyThing] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await getMyThing(id);

            setMyThing(result);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [id, getMyThing]);
}
```

Or if you don't want to introduce an `async` function:

```
import { getMyThing } from '../../utils/databaseCalls'

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [myThing, setMyThing] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getMyThing()
            .then(result => setMyThing(result));
    }, [id, getMyThing]);
}
```

Also, take note of the `[id, getMyThing]` part as it is important. This is a dependency array determining when your `useEffect` hooks are gonna execute/re-execute.

Comment: Thanks for the great response but I still can't get it to work. I added the database call (which might be where the problem is) in a comment above if you don't mind taking a look.

Comment: @JohnWLIV I've added a comment on your question after the edit. It will solve the issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

If `getMyThing` returns a Promise, the `myThing` will be set to that Promise on the first render, and then `myThing` will stay referring to that Promise. `setMyThing(myThing)` just sets the state to the Promise again - it's superfluous.

Call the asynchronous method inside the effect hook instead:

```
const [myThing, setMyThing] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    getMyThing(id)
        .then(setMyThing);
}, []);
```

Here, `myThing` will start out `undefined`, and will be then set to the result of the async call as soon as it resolves.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the initial state with a value obtained asynchronously because you can't have the value in time.

`myThing` cannot both return the value you want **and** be asynchronous. Maybe it returns a promise that resolves to what you want.

Set an **initial** value with some default data. This might be null data (and later when you return some JSX from your component you can special case `myThing === null` by, for example, returning a Loading message).

```
const [myThing, setMyThing] = useState(null);
```

Trigger the asynchronous call in `useEffect`, much like you are doing now, but:

- Make it rerun when the data it *depends on* changes, not when the data it sets changes.
- Deal with whatever asynchronous mechanism your code uses. In this example I'll assume it returns a promise.

Thus:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const myNewThing = await getMyThing(id);
    setMyThing(myNewThing)
}, [id]);
```